# Pause other instances of AVPlayer when playButton is pushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard, avplayer

I have Table View with cells loading video objects from Parse. 
When the video is loaded a playButton appears over a still image representation of the video. The play button is an outlet to a storyboard UIButton.

In my FeedCell.m:

```
- (IBAction)playButtonTapped:(id)sender {
[self.player play];

if (self.player.rate != 0 && (self.player.error == nil)) {
    // player is playing
    self.playButton.hidden = YES;
}

self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector: @selector (playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                            name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                            object:[self.player currentItem]];
}

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
self.playButton.hidden = NO;
[self.playerItem seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[self.player pause];
}
```

I would like to add to the functionality of this button so that when the playButton is tapped the AVPlayerItem will play and all other instances of AVPlayers will be paused.

Am I able to do this by setting up another NSNotification?

Answer (score 0):

NSNotification is not the answer because it sends a broadcast message to all the receiver added as observer,in this case each cell containing the AVPlayers.

But there's a problem: as soon as you scroll the UITableView down, some UITableViewCells go out of screen and they won't receive any NSNotification even if they are added as observers.

So you could add all your AVPlayers to an NSMutableArray and when you want to stop all videos you could cycle the array and manually call the stop method on them.
Then remove them from the array.
Keep in mind that adding AVPlayers to an array cause their reference count to never reach 0 so they are not deallocated while the array is alive.
So put the NSMutableArray on the same controller which contains the UITableView so when it's deallocated,the array is also deallocated and then all AVPlayers are deallocated

Comment: Is there a way to just affect cells that have scrolled out of view?

Comment: You could use an `AVQueuePlayer` instead. Which will let you preload assets and then anytime a playButton is pressed, it will stop the asset that is playing and go to the new one